# Is it possible to partition a square into finitely many triangles such that no two triangles share a side?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

Here is a problem from Miklos Schweitzer competition from 2017.

**Is it possible to partition a square into finitely many triangles such that no two triangles share a side?**

I believe it is impossible. I tried proving that the polygon formed by triangles (without sharing any side) must have a concave angle ($>\angle180^{\circ}$), but... or maybe just making concave polygons with the triangles...

Help guys!

Comment: It suffices to show that you can't bisect a square into two noncontiguous triangles.

Comment: See [KöMaL](https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=feladat&f=A710&l=en). I'm not sure this is close enough to warrant locking it until the contest closes? Better safe than...